# Gulp error internal/child_process.js:298 throw errnoException(err, 'spawn'); Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: gulp

I searched for the cause of this error and found that I have to change permissions or run gulp using sudo, but still got the same error.
Can anyone please help...

internal/child_process.js:298
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at exports.execFile (child_process.js:151:15)
    at ExecBuffer. (/var/www/conFusion/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/exec-buffer/index.js:91:3)
    at /var/www/conFusion/node_modules/gulp-rev/node_modules/vinyl-file/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at /var/www/conFusion/node_modules/gulp-cache/node_modules/cache-swap/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at /var/www/conFusion/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like you don't have permission to run some files, 
Try by typing next command on the root path of your project:

```
chmod -R u+x .
```

If it is fixed now you must find which files had the incorrect permissions.
Type next command if you want to undo changes to find those problematic files:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the imagemin related error by adding those permissions to the node_modules folder only.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the solution is just to easy to be seen. Saved me some time.

Comment: Thanks. As @jwinn mentioned - executing `chmod -R u+x node_modules` solved the problem.